# Sbt doesn't enable some custom plugins

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I've written autoPlugin like so

```
object ThriftIfaceSbt extends AutoPlugin {

  override def projectSettings = {
    Seq(
      crossVersion := {
        println(s"Init ThriftIfaceSbt ${name.value}")
        CrossVersion.Disabled
      },
      autoScalaLibrary := false,
      resourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "thrift"
    )
  }

}
```

Then i publishLocal and try it in my build.sbt

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file("a")).enablePlugins(ThriftIfaceSbt)
```

That plugin doesn't get applied to project.. i don't understand why.

It it possible that SBT silently ignores my plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely reason that it's not working is because you're overriding settings provided by the sbt `JvmPlugin`, but you don't declare a dependency on it, so the order that they get applied is undefined. If your plugin gets applied first, then the `JvmPlugin` settings will override whatever your plugin has configured.

You need to add:

```
override def requires = sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
```

to your plugin. Even if this doesn't fix your issue, you'll still need to add that.